# Modify existing circuitikz

Tags: circuitikz

does someone know how can I modify this code which offers as a result:

[image]

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
%--------start graphics code --------
\draw[step=0.5,very thin,black!20] (-1,-0.5);
\path (0,0) coordinate (ref_gnd);
\draw
  (ref_gnd) to[american voltage source=\(V\),invert] ++(0,2)
            to[R=\(R_1\)] ++(3,0) 
            to[L=\(L_1\)] ++(3,0) 
            to[american voltage source=\(V\)] ++(0,-2) 
  -- (ref_gnd);
%--------end graphics code ----------
\end{tikzpicture}
```

To create this: [image]

Thank you so much

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A rude but working solution:

**Edit:**
now added with voltage source symbol as shown in image in the question:

**Edit (2):**
removed is not used code fragments and further simplified code with use `mirror` option for inductance.

```
\documentclass[margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{circuitikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\begin{document}
\begin{circuitikz}[american, cute inductors, node distance=0mm]
%--------start graphics code --------
\coordinate (ref_gnd);
\draw
  (ref_gnd) to[esource, l=\(e(t)\),name=VS1] ++(0,2)
            to[R=\(R_1\)] ++(3,0) 
            to[L=\(L_1\), mirror] ++(3,0)
            to[esource, l=\(e(t)\),name=VS2] ++(0,-2)
            to[short,f_=\(i(t)\), current arrow scale=16] (ref_gnd);
\node[above left=of VS1.e] {+}; % "e": east
\node[above right=of VS2.w] {+};% "w"; west
%--------end graphics code ----------
\end{circuitikz}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much for all. It's perfect

Comment: @AlejandroFernándezSuárez, you are welcome! See edited answer, now the code is more simple.

Answer (score 2):

[image]

from page 53 of the manual -- you need to change the following line in your code

```
(ref_gnd) to[american voltage source=\(V\),invert] ++(0,2)
```

to

```
(ref_gnd) to[esource, l=$v(t)$] ++(0,2)
```

this will give a blank voltage source